# How to add hourly seasonality in facebook prophet in python

Tags: python, prediction, predict, facebook-prophet, prophet

could you, please, help me: I don't know how to add hourly seasonality in Facebook Prophet in Python. I tried the following:

```
m = Prophet(
            weekly_seasonality = True, 
            yearly_seasonality = True, 
            daily_seasonality = True
            )

m.fit(train_df)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=24, freq = 'H')
forecast = m.predict(future)
```

But it didn't help me. The results were strange. Maybe you know the solution how to add both daily, weekly etc and hourly seasonality?

Comment: The code looks ok. Can you share the plot of the data and plot_components output? It is hard to say what is wrong here and what do you mean by 'strange output'. Maybe model settings are not appropriate for your timeseries - there is more to adjust in Prophet model than just seasonality.

Answer (score 1):

Just check a [docs](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/seasonality,_holiday_effects,_and_regressors.html#specifying-custom-seasonalities).
So basically you need to create a custom seasonality with a proper period. E.g. if you have a step 1 day your hourly seasonality will be with period 1/24